# Installed gems lost after gem update

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I performed a gem update using

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
```

and

```
sudo update_rubygems
```

But now all my previously installed gems have disappeared. I ran

```
gem list
```

and no locally installed gems showed up.
Any ideas what went wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I've had issues with using 'sudo' and then not, have you tried sudo gem list?

Comment: Okay, apparently, my previous version of rubygems was installed at /var/lib, which was changed by the update to /usr/lib/... and thus my previously installed gems disappeared. Luckily, once I re-installed the required gems to the new path, my other problem with fxruby resolved too.